# FXML Loader does not create new instance

Tags: java, javafx, spring-boot, fxml, fxmlloader

I have a JavaFX + Spring Boot application. When I try to load new FXML with its controller it works fine, but when I load it second or third time, it gives me the same instance and does not create a new one.

My FXML loader as follows:

```
public <T> T loadAndGetController(String fxmlPath) throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setControllerFactory(context::getBean); // Spring now FXML Controller Factory
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource(fxmlPath));
    loader.setResources(ResourceBundle.getBundle("language/lang",
            new Locale(languageController.getLanguage().getValue(), languageController.getLanguage().toString())));
    loader.load();
    return loader.getController();
}
```

Loading new FXML:

```
TabController tabController = (TabController) StageManager.loadAndGetController(FXMLViews.TAB.getFxmlFile());
```

And when I try to add it in my loaded controller list, the IDs are the same, as the hash codes, which means it is the same instance. Thus it didn't create a new one.

[image]

Maybe I'm loading my FXMLs wrong or just the Spring-Boot controller factory works weird in this case. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the scope of `context`, and how is `getBean` implemented? If there is only one instance of `context` and it always returns the same controller, then there will only ever be one.

Comment: Isn't this exactly what spring is supposed to do with it's singleton beans???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
loader.setControllerFactory(context::getBean);
```

instructs the `FXMLLoader` to get the controller from the spring application context: internally, the `FXMLLoader` will now do something like

```
Class controllerClass = Class.forName(classNameFromFXMLFile);
Object controller = context.getBean(controllerClass);
```

The behavior of `getBean` depends on how you configured the bean for that class, but by default it will have "singleton" scope. This means it will create one instance of the class, and return the same instance every time `getBean(...)` is invoked with an argument mapping to that bean (e.g. the class of the bean).

You almost certainly want a new instance of the controller class each time you load the FXML file, so you should configure the bean to have "prototype" scope. With "prototype" scope, a new instance will be created each time.

The mechanism for defining the scope of the bean depends on how you are configuring your application context, but with annotation-based config you would do something like

```
@Component
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class FarTabController { /* ... */ }
```

With Java-based config you would do

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    @Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public FarTabController farTabController() {
        return new FarTabController() ;
    }

    // ...
}
```

and if you are still using the old schema-based (XML) configuration, you would do (if I remember correctly)

```xml
<beans>

    <bean class="my.package.FarTabController" scope="prototype" />

    <!-- ... -->

</beans>
```

Comment: Thank you! I just added my controller to my ApplicationConfig class with beans, changed to prototype scope and now everything works great!